# Not in scope, whereas it is called by its full name

Tags: haskell

A simple question:

```
case (HashMap.lookup "last" jsonObject) of
  (Just (String val)) -> Data.Text.IO.putStrLn val
```

It says `Not in scope: Data.Text.IO.putStrLn`. How could it be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Haskell source files, you also have to import any modules you wish to use - just referring to symbols by their qualified name isn't enough.

So add

```
import qualified Data.Text.IO
```

to the top of your source file. If you also want to refer to `putStrLn` directly, you can omit the `qualified` keyword

In this particular case you'd also need to "hide" the version from the `Prelude` to do that, because `putStrLn` is a standard library function.

```
import Prelude hiding ( putStrLn )
```

Note that it is possible to refer to symbols directly at the ghci prompt which may have been a source of confusion here.

Comment: Though ghci (but not ghc) will just access any module whose name you use as a name qualifier.

Comment: You could also use qualified import here.